# Are contractible open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that every contractible open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: The title is somewhat opaque...

Comment: Related MathOverflow questions: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64192/is-there-a-classification-of-open-subsets-of-euclidean-space-up-to-homeomorphism, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4468/what-are-the-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-that-are-diffeomorphic-to-mathbb

Comment: The whitehead manifold is a counterexample in dimension 3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold

Answer (score 50):

The answer to your general question is "no".

A contractible open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ need not be "simply connected at
infinity". ( "$X$ is simply connected at infinity" means that for each
compact $K$ there is a larger compact $L$ such that the induced map on
$\pi_1$ from $X - L$ to $X - K$ is trivial.)

A contractible open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ which *is* simply connected
at infinity is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$

a) if $n > 4$: by J. Stallings, The piecewise linear structure of Euclidean space, Proc Camb Phil Soc 58(1962) (481-88)

b) $n = 4$: by M. Freedman - see Topology of 4-Manifolds by Freedman and Quinn.

c) For $n = 3$ this is a standard exercise - I don't know who gets the credit,
but you oould refer to  AMS memoir 411  by Brin and Thickstun.

The ingredients are

1. the Loop theorem and
2. Alexander's theorem

that a PL sphere in $\Bbb R^3$ bounds a 3-ball - you could even get around that by using the generalized Schoenfliess theorem of Morton Brown.

Comment: Great answer! ${}$

Comment: @m-winter for n=1, 2 and n>4 they are in fact diffeomorphic. Do you know something about n=3? And clearly it is not the case for n=4.