# How can I prove that two sets are isomorphic, short of finding the isomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a set $E \subset X$ within a metric space ($X, d$).  I want to prove that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, in the sense that there exists a continuous bijection between the two.  Because $E$ is a fairly complicated set, it would be a huge pain to actually find an exact bijection, so instead I hope to identify a sufficient suite of conditions that I can test $E$ for that will suffice to show that the two are isomorphic.

Is there some sort of known method for doing this?  Or will I have to find the exact function?

Thanks.

Comment: What are $E$ and $X$?

Comment: It need not be the case in general, i.e. $\Bbb Q$ is not homeomorphic/isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer $X$ is $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and $E$ is a strange set within that that would take a fair amount of effort to explain.  I hope to find a test suite of conditions that applies to any $E$ we might choose.

Comment: @Clayton I don't follow: I don't believe there is a continuous bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @LevDub: There isn't; that is what I was getting at. If $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $E=\mathbb{Q}$, then there doesn't exist what you're asking for. You'll be better off putting in the question what it is you have and want exactly.

Comment: @Clayton Ah, I understand now.  My question is "does there exist a condition (or set of conditions) such that $E$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are isomorphic iff $E$ satisfies the condition(s)?"  So it would defeat the purpose to specify $E$.

Comment: Are you sure that you only want to show that there is a continuous bijection between the two? This does not in general imply that they are homeomorphic (or isometrically isomorphic, for that matter).

Comment: @Brad that's interesting, I didn't know that.  What's an example of a continuous bijection with a non-continuous inverse?

Comment: Would a better title for your post be "what properties characterize $\Bbb R^n$ among metric spaces"?

Comment: @LevDub The map $f:[0,2\pi)\to S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(t) = e^{it}$ is continuous and bijective, but its inverse is not continuous at the point $1$.

Comment: Note that your notion of "isomorphism" is not the same as the notion of isomorphism in the category of metric spaces, which is customary called "homeomorphism".

Comment: A continuous bijection of manifolds *is* an homeomorpism, as a consequence of the theorem of Invariance of Domain. It is important here that there be no boundaries (although this extends to manifolds with compact boundaries, iirc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The necessary and sufficient set of conditions for $E$ to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{m}$ (in your situation $m=n^2$):

- $E$ must be a [topological manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold) of dimension $m$
- $E$ must be [contractible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible)
- $E$ must be [simply connected at infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_at_infinity)

[More details here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55114/are-contractible-open-sets-in-mathbbrn-homeomorphic-to-mathbb-rn).

Comment: Perfect!  This is exactly the sort of list I was hoping existed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another less general, but easier solution is that if $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a [star-shaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain) (or less generally [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set)) open set, then $E$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Note that the converse is not true. The idea of the proof is to expand the shape radially in such a way that the map stays continuous. More details can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4468/what-are-the-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-that-are-diffeomorphic-to-mathbb).