# Are any two open connected subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Are any two open, connected subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic?  This seems intuitively true.

Comment: See: [necessary and sufficient conditions to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/283260/53153).

Comment: Think about donuts and disks.

Answer (score 20):

**1** $\neq$ **0** $\neq$ **8**

(Think of these as being open subsets of the plane. The set consists of the area that is colored black. Remove the infinitely thin boundary)

Comment: I am not sure how to think of these as open subsets of the plane? Certainly not 1...

Comment: This is a bit mysterious to me. I see $0$, but $1$ and $8$...

Comment: I think the idea is that you should draw the symbols in the plane, and then take small open neighbourhoods of them.

Comment: The set consists of the area that is colored black. Remove the infinitely thin boundary.

Comment: I see. Is this standard algebraic topology notation?

Comment: I guess the point would come across better in bold font: **1**, **0**, **8**.

Comment: @5pm: Indeed. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @julien: I don't think so. On the board, you would of course make a nicer drawing.

Answer (score 7):

When $n>1$, an open annulus 
$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid a<|x|<b\},\quad 0<a<b$$
and an open ball
$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid |x|<r\},\quad 0<r$$
are open connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are not homeomorphic.

When $n=1$ or $0$, it is true that any open connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are homeomorphic. This is because any open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is an open interval, and $\mathbb{R}^0$ is just a point.

Answer (score 6):

Nope ! For example $\rm B(0, 2)$ is not homeomorphic to $\rm B(0,2) \backslash \rm \overline{B(0,1)}$.

Comment: If the statement was refined to say: any two open, simply-connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, would the statement then be true?

Comment: @Lev: It certainly would not be true for $n>2$ because these spaces are simply-connected in that case.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Great point, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @LevLivnev: in higher dimensions one should then replace simply connected with "n-connected."

Comment: @LevLivnev the idea holds when you define higher dimensional analogues to "simply connected". The idea behind these examples is the fact that the fundamental groups of these spaces are non-isomorphic, the fundamental groups $\pi_n$ detect $n$-dimensional holes. I have no idea to justify this without using these concepts. Has anyone other explanation?

Comment: @ViniciusM. There are contractible open manifolds that are not homeomorphic to Euclidean space, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold  Does this answer your question?