# Any open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

I believe the claim is right. But I can only prove for the case where the open set is convex.

EDIT: As someone pointed out, it is not true in general. How about "simply connected open set"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A set of conditions for which this becomes true is given [on another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55114/are-contractible-open-sets-in-mathbbrn-homeomorphic-to-mathbb-rn), but the proof appears to be quite nontrivial. In brief, an open set which is contractable and satisfies a certain "boundary" connectedness condition is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$.

To address the edit: contractibility is a stronger condition than simply connectedness, and so we would not necessarily expect it to be enough. Indeed it is not. Take an open annulus and spin it around a diameter in 3-space; the result is a "thickened" 2-sphere. This is an open set which is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^3$.

In some sense, simply connectedness removes the possibility of "1-dimensional holes" (i.e. holes that can be surrounded by a 1-sphere). But you need to also account for higher dimensional holes in general; this is the intuitive notion formalized by contractibility.

Answer (score 7):

It is not true in general. For example, $\mathbb R^2$ minus one point is open but not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ (say, because it isn't simply connected).

Answer (score 4):

In general the result is not true. For example $B(0,1)\cup B((2,\ldots,0),\frac{1}{2}))$ is an open set and it cannot be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected but the topological space  $B(0,1)\cup B((2,\ldots,0),\frac{1}{2}))$ is not connected.